# toggle effect read more

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="post-content">
        <p>Random text >Random text >Random text Random text >Random text >Random text Random text >Random text >Random text Random text >Random text >Random text Random text >Random text >Random text Random text >Random text >Random text Random text >Random text >Random text Random text >Random text >Random text Random text >Random text >Random text Random text >Random text >Random text Random text >Random text >Random text Random text >Random text >Random text </p>
        <p>More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text </p> 
        <span class="more">more/less</span>
</div>
```

---

```
$('.post-content p:not(:first-child)').css('display', 'none');

$(".more").click(function () {
    $('.post-content p:not(:first-child)').css('display', 'block');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pvwp6/1/)

The problem is obvious. I need to make a toogle effect to show hide all `p` after the first paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `hide` and `toggle` instead:

```
// cache elements so you don't repeatedly query the DOM
toggleParas = $('.post-content p:not(:first-child)');

toggleParas.hide();

$(".more").click(function () {
    toggleParas.toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pvwp6/2/)*

```
$('.post-content p:eq(1)').hide();

$(".more").click(function () {
   $(this).prev('p').slideToggle();
});
```